# Blackberry listfield item adding to a horizontal manager

Tags: blackberry

i have a listfield where i am adding the contents in a horizontal field manager first and then adding the manager to a vertical manager. Visually:

```
----Image ---Text   ----Image
          ---Text   ----Image
          ---Image
```

How can i achieve this using a horizontal field manager

Answer (score 2):

You might want to clear up the question a bit, but I'll try to answer what I think you're asking. ListFields don't support (natively) drawing a Manager as its row -- or a Field for that matter. What you'll need to do is in your ListFieldCallback's `drawListRow()` method, emulate this by doing the painting the way you want it to look. It would end up being measurements with `bitmap.getWidth()` and `font.getAdvance(text)` to figure out where to draw the images and text, but it should be a simple enough process.